# Rails how to reference what's already inside a block from outside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to obtain result variable from block outside the block before the iteration actually starts?

I want to be able to get `active` variable and output next to where `"collapse"` is.

Below is my code so far.

```
def sidebar_menu_item(top_menu_args, data_target, sub_menu_args, icon = "angle-left")
        haml_tag :li, :class => "panel" do
            haml_tag:a, :href => "#", :class => "accordion-toggle", "data-present" => "#menu", "data-toggle" => "collapse", "data-target" => "##{data_target}" do
                haml_concat "<i class='fa fa-#{top_menu_args[1]}'></i> #{top_menu_args[0]}"
                haml_tag :span, :class => "pull-right" do
                    haml_tag :i, :class => "fa fa-angle-left"
                end
            end
            haml_tag :ul, :class => "collapse", :id => data_target do
                sub_menu_args.each do |menu_args|
                    link = menu_args[0]
                    label = menu_args[1]
                    action = "/#{params[:action]}" if params[:action] != "index"
                    current_uri = "/#{params[:controller]}#{action}"
                    if link == current_uri
                        active = { :class => "active" }
                    end
                    haml_tag :li, active do
                        haml_tag :a, :href => link do
                            haml_concat "<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i> #{label}"
                        end 
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: Please format your code. It's very difficult to read. Remember, in Ruby it's always 1 Tab == 2 spaces.

Comment: helper methods aren't for this kind of Rails madness.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Haml, but can you do something like this?

You can pass the target into the current_page method, like this:

```
current_page?(root_path)
```

It will return true or false.  Then have something like:

```
:class => ("active" if current_page?(root_path))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate with map rather than each it will return array of elements

```
sub_menu_args.map do |menu_args|
                link = menu_args[0]
                label = menu_args[1]
                action = "/#{params[:action]}" if params[:action] != "index"
                current_uri = "/#{params[:controller]}#{action}"
                active = { :class => "active" } if (link ==current_uri)                 
            end
```